# Compiling React projects in MonoRepo failing

Tags: javascript, docker, webpack, lerna

I'm trying to setup yarn workspaces with my docker instance. This is my directory structure:

```
/monorepo/
  /node_modules/
        @libs/common
        @services/common
        @services/project-A
        ...OTHER DEPS...
  package.json
  /services/
      /common/
         index.jsx
         package.json
      /project-A/  
           webpack.base.config.js
           **REACT project with babel, webpack, etc**

  /libs/
     /tools/
         /common/
            index.jsx
            package.json
```

To simplify my docker setup I just configured this volume within my docker compose that maps the entire monorepo directory:

```
volumes:
      - '../../../monorepo:/monorepo'
```

From there in my Project-A I import @libs/common and @services/common. This works fine when the common libraries are exporting simple functions like:

`export const Add = (a,b) => a+b`

Webpack has no issue resolving this and building Project-A.

However when I try to import a component from one of the common libraries like this:

```
/libs/tools/common: 

      import React from 'react' 
      export MySharedComponent = () => <>HELLLO</>
```

I get an error in the build process:

```
 Error: Cannot find module '/monorepo/libs/tools/common/webpack.base.config.js'
Require stack:
- /monorepo/node_modules/eslint-import-resolver-webpack/index.js
- /monorepo/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/resolve.js
- /monorepo/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/rules/no-unresolved.js
- /monorepo/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/index.js
```

The eslint file under Project-A:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "jest": true,
      "cypress/globals": true
    },
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "webpack": {
          "config": "webpack.base.config.js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The babel.rc under Project-A

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-webpack-alias",
          {
            "config": "./webpack.base.config.js"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My Question:

- Is the main issue that there's no webpack config set up in the common repositories. Therefore the workspace does not know how to compile my shared resources?
- Should there only be 1 webpack build config in my workspace used by all projects within the workspace? Currently I only have 1 config under Project-A?
- What happens if I have specific webpack needs per project, does 1 config (if that's the answer) make sense?

Answer (score 0):

1) **First**, there is a line in your code that you are referring to `webpack.base.config.js` in both `babelrc` and `eslint`,

so if that file does not exist, this error that says module not found makes sense.

2) **Second**: if you build and use your repositories in the same situation and environment, yes you can have one config for both but you might need environment setup (`Development, Production`) for your config.
But if you really want to make your dependencies and configs apart, webpack support [multiple entries](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) for your project which you can check that out.

Comment: So the webpack.base.config does exist but it is in `Project-A`, however i'm trying to bundle 'Project-A' which relies on `@libs/common`, I get an error saying that `webpack.base.config.js` is not under `@libs/common`. However shouldn't webpack just use the config from `Project-A`

I don't think multiple entries is the solution to this.

Comment: Or if you could give an example about the entries that might help me understand what you mean.

Comment: @Batman Every time webpack wants to load the file or module you attempt to import, it passes that file to kind of a middleware based on the directory the file is in.
So your relative pass could be wrong too ("webpack.base.config.js") . Of course, multiple entries are not a solution to your question. I think you do not need multiple config files, but it would be a case if you want it.

Comment: When you say my relative pass I believe you're referring to my `babelrc` file where I have `"./webpack.base.config.js"`? So instead of looking for the webpack config under `project-a` it's looking for it relative to `libs/tools/common`? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Batman Suppose you have 2 separate applications with different files and folders that have also a common shared library, you create 2 webpack entries, you put shared modules in share folder and both entries use that shared library. You could search for detail .

Comment: @Batman I thought in eslint.rc "webpack.base.confg.js" could be wrong, please change it to "./" to test that out

Comment: Didn't make a difference